# Connect to a server with keyboard-interactive password authentication using jsch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

I'm connecting to a remote machine without keyboard-interactive authentication, using the above snippet.

But when I'm trying to connect to a server with keyboard-interactive password, I'm getting a 
`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail` exception.

I added these config and tested, yet didn't succed.

```
config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
```

and

```
config.put("PreferredAuthentications",
                    "keyboard-interactive,password");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
    JSch jSch;
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        properties.put("UseDNS", "no");

        jSch = new JSch();
        Session session = jSch.getSession("username", "host/ip", 22);
        session.setConfig(properties);
        session.setTimeout(10 * 1_000);
        session.setPassword("password");
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect using keyboard-interactive password authentications

use config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "keyboard-interactive");

If you want to connect using password-prompt password authentications

use config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "password");